# std::unordered_map with repeated elements stored as references in different keys

Tags: c++, caching, std, tiles

I have an unordered map of objects, like this:

```
unordered_map<int, shared_ptr<Tile>>
```

I want to create my `Tile` only once, and reuse it whenever I can. How can I store that in the most efficient way inside the map and access it later?

I thought about simply searching for the index and, if found, creating a new index with the same element. However, that doesn't seem to work.

The code is this:

```
pair<int, shared_ptr<Tile>> pair = make_pair(id, tile);

if (this->tiles.count(id) > 0) {
    this->tiles[cacheCounter--] = this->tiles.at(id);
} else {
    this->tiles.insert(pair);
}
```

And the result is somewhat like this:

[image]

As you can see, the empty spaces are supposed to be composed of existing tiles.

Comment: What is the relationship between `id` and `cacheCounter`?

Comment: They are both integers. `id` is a unique one and `cacheCounter` is an incremental integer that I use for storing a reference to objects with the same `id`

Comment: But you're using them both as keys into the map. It's unclear to me how you ensure that `cacheCounter` can never have the same value as an `id` (assuming that's what you want). Can you [edit] your question to elaborate a little (in non-code) on how the map is intended to be used? What does `id` actually *mean?*

Comment: Edited the title. Not sure if I can explain the issue more than what I already did. `id` is a unique integer that means the tile number in a tile set texture. I don't want to create the same tile over and over if I could just use a reference to the same object.

Comment: I would understand `tiles` as a lookup map from an ID to a tile. But you apparently want to have several IDs for the same tile? That's what the code is effectively doing. Can you explain that?

Comment: Yes, I want to have several different **unique** keys pointing to the same Tile object which was created when the `id` key didn't already exist in the map. The reason I want to create the duplicates is that I have to iterate through the map to render it later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114251/discussion-between-angew-and-daniel-ribeiro).